# Can't solve an exercise from a book

Tags: c#

This is the exercise:

Write a program, which reads two arrays from the console and checks whether they are equal (two arrays are equal when they are of equal length and all of their elements, which have the same index, are equal).

This is my code:

```
        //Declaration, Initialization.
        Console.Write("First array size: ");
        int sizeOfFirstArray = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] firstArray = new int[sizeOfFirstArray];

        Console.Write("Second array size: ");
        int sizeOfSecondArray = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] secondArray= new int[sizeOfSecondArray];

        // Checking if Array's are equal.

        bool isEqual = true;

        for (int a = 0; a < firstArray.Length; a++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter first array's values of element: {0}", a);
            firstArray[a] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int b = 0; b < secondArray.Length; b++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter second array's values of element: {0}", b);
            secondArray[b] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        if (firstArray[firstArray.Length] != secondArray[secondArray.Length]) // This gives me an error Index was out of bounds
        {
            isEqual = false;
        }$
```

I want to solve this exercise with for loops.

Problem: 
Line 38 gives me an error: Index was outside of the array boundries.

Comment: You can't just throw down your partial work like this. Try finishing it, and come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: Narrow your problem. What output do you expect? What are you getting instead? Have you ran it through the debugger yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is in the

```
  if (firstArray[firstArray.Length]...
```

since arrays are *zero-based* they have items of `[0..Length - 1]` indexes; you mean

```
  // if lengths (not items!) are different then arrays are not equal
  if (firstArray.Length != secondArray.Length) {
    isEqual = false;
  }
```

Just do as it's written in the book:

```
  ...

   // Two arrays are equal if they are of equal length...
   bool isEqual = a.Length == b.Length;

   // ..and all of their elements which have the same index, are equal
   if (isEqual) // We don't need to scan arrays if they are not equal by their lengths 
     for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
       if (a[i] != b[i]) {
         isEqual = false; // 1st counter example has been found

         // we don't need to loop any more if a counter example has been found
         break; 
       }
```

Please, notice that in Real World we put

```
bool isEqual = a.SequenceEqual(b);
```

Comment: Thanks! Where do I put this code based on my example?

Comment: @SUNDIUS: instead of `if (firstArray[firstArray.Length] != secondArray[secondArray.Length]) // This gives me an error Index was out of bounds
        {
            isEqual = false;
        }$`

Comment: by the way we could check the length equality before even reading the arrays from the user

Comment: @niceman: yes we can, but mixing code, user input (UI) and business logic (arrays comparison) is a bad practice. If it's not just an exercise, I'll *extract two methods*: array's input and arrays comparison.

Comment: Your way works too, but I finally started thinking more and solved this problem my way. :D